# Indefinite quaternion algebra over Q

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, quaternions, division-algebras

Let $D$ be an indefinite quaternion algebra over $\Bbb Q$. We have a chosen isomorphism $\iota \colon D \otimes_{\Bbb Q} {\Bbb R} \cong {\mathrm{M}}_2({\Bbb R})$.

Q: If we choose another isomorphism $\iota' \colon D \otimes_{\Bbb Q} {\Bbb R} \cong {\mathrm{M}}_2({\Bbb R})$. Is it true that $\iota(D) = a\,\iota'(D)\,a^{-1}$ always for some element $a \in {\mathrm{GL}}_2({\Bbb R})$?

I do not see how I should use Skolem-Noether theorem. 
Please help.

Comment: "every automorphism of a central simple $\Bbbk$-algebra is an inner automorphism"

Comment: Consider $\iota '\circ\iota ^{-1}$, and please stop asking elementary questions on MO -- use MSE instead.

Answer (score 2):

The automorphism $\iota \circ \iota'^{-1}$ of $M_2(\mathbb R)$ is conjugation by some $a \in GL_2(\mathbb R)$. Comparing the images of $\iota'(D)$, we get:
$$(\iota \circ \iota'^{-1})(\iota'(D)) = a \iota'(D) a^{-1}$$
which is what you want.